# Plotting each beat of a heart in my signal

Tags: matlab, plot

[image: This is the plot that I am currently using.]

I tried using

```
pks=findpeaks(filtered_ecg)
findpeaks(filtered_ecg)
maxIndicies = isLocalmax(ecg)
```

and then printing gave me a more condensed plot but I am trying figure it out still as I am very new to MatLab. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You should add more of your code in order to get a helpful response. You don't show where `ecg` is defined, nor your plotting commands. Probably you want to loop through your list of `maxIndices`, using those values to index the ecg signal, and plot 200ms before and after to show the entire QR complex.

Comment: What do you want to plot about the heartbeats?  The code that you shared (giving "maxIndicies") suggests that you just want to know the time (index) of each heartbeat.  Is this what you want?  Also, you presumably want your detector to trigger on the R-wave of the ECG and not on the P- or T- wave.  You can achieve this through carefully choosing the frequency bounds to filter away the P and T waves (thereby leaving only the R-wave) before you do the peak detection.